# Dynamic folder paths for JSON file from CSVs?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I have following python code which I am using to create the JSON file. I need to run this code multiple times for my project — i.e. 150 times. Is there any way I can make it dynamic? For the entire code only last two characters are changing in the given: `path_to_folder = "C:\\Users\\CSVs\\AO"`.

```
import csv
import json
import glob
import os

class csv2jsonindirectory():
    def Python_trial(self):
        # Update the following variable with the path in windows and replace
        # every "\" with "/".
        path_to_folder = "C:\\Users\\CSVs\\AO"
        csv_files_in_folder = path_to_folder + '/*.csv'
        csvfilenames = []
        i = 1
        mydict = {}
        for filename in glob.glob(csv_files_in_folder):
            csvfilenames.append(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])
            rows = []
        for i in range(len(csvfilenames)):
            with open(csvfilenames[i] + ".csv", "r") as f:
                csvreader = csv.DictReader(f)
                rows = list(csvreader)
                mydict["chartdiv" + str(i + 1)] = rows

        print(mydict)

        with open(csvfilenames[0] + ".json", 'w') as f:
            json.dump(mydict, f, indent= 4)


dd = csv2jsonindirectory()
dd.Python_trial()
```

Comment: Why is `csv2jsonindirectory` a class? It has only one method, and that method doesn't use the instance (`self`) at all.

Comment: Yes, it possible. What do you want to change the last two characters into? What is the source of that information. You also likely don't need to be changing the backslashes into forwardslashes.

Comment: I want to change ( two digits values in the path upto 150.. i.e  AA, AB, AC, AD.......  These are the folder names in which my CSV are parked.....

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure that I understand you correctly. If you want to perform this taks for different paths, you may do so by adding an `__init__()` method to this class that takes the path as an argument. Then you can just loop through directories:

```
class csv2jsonindirectory():
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path = path
    def Python_trial(self):
        # Update the following variable with the path in windows and replace
        # every "\" with "/".
        csv_files_in_folder = self.path + '/*.csv'
        
   ### [Remainder of your code]



for folder in ["A0","A1","A3"]:
    path = "C:/Users/CSVs/"+folder
    dd = csv2jsonindirectory(path)
    dd.Python_trial()
```

Comment: my folder is changing (A1, A2, A3 ect) in the same path. Let me try if its work....

Comment: "is not working" is rather vague. What exactly is not working and what are the error messages? You can update your initial post to include your whole code and the error.

Answer (score 0):

Did some research and finally find the answer....

```
import csv
import json
import os
import time

class csv2jsonindirectory():
    
    def Python_trial(self):
        # Update the following variable with the path in windows and replace
        # every "\" with "/".
        
        path_to_folder = "CSV Folder Path"

        path = "Path to folder to save JSON files"

        for root , dirs, files in os.walk(path_to_folder):
            print(os.path.basename(root))
            csv_files = []
            mydict= {}
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.csv'):
                    file_path = root+'/'+file
                    csv_files.append(file_path)
            for i in range(len(csv_files)):
                with open(csv_files[i]) as f:
                     csvreader = csv.DictReader(f)
                     rows = list(csvreader)
                     mydict["chartdiv" + str(i + 1)] = rows
            with open(path+'/' +os.path.basename(root)+ ".json", 'w') as f:
                  json.dump(mydict, f, indent= 4)
            del csv_files
            del mydict
start = time.time()                  
dd = csv2jsonindirectory()
dd.Python_trial()
end=time.time()
print(end - start)
```